# If two people have the same aura item, do they stack?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Items Can Be Stacked?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60016/which-items-can-be-stacked)

Say I bought a mana manipulator and some one else bought the same thing, would we get double the effect? and does this also work on items like Infinity Edge?

Answer (score 1):

Constant Aura's do not stack anymore.  The way Aura items work is that the person that buys that item receives a Buff and everyone around them receives an Aura.  Now if someone else buys the same item the two people with the item will have the buff from having the item in their inventory and receive the aura from the other person with the item.

Here is a link with more information on specific champion aura's  and further backing up my explanation

- http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aura

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that they do. I think if the item's Aura is not a Unique Aura then it would stack. For example Aegis of the Legion: UNIQUE Aura: +12 Armor / +15 Magic Resistance / +8 Damage to nearby allied champions. That means that this Aura does not stack with others so getting two one would just override the other causing only one to be active.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that aegis can stack like wota does. the way it works is only between the people who have the items. so people around you won't get double the spell vamp. Only the two people will have the double aura. This is also the same with aegis of the legion. So if amumu had an aegis he would get the aura. if galio also had an aegis amumu would get the bonus galio's aura and galio would get the bonus of amumu aura even though they both already have aegis. however the malz who didn't buy an aegis would not have both the auras.

Hope that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Aegis and will of the ancients are items that u can have 1 by urself and a teammate have one too and you will get the double effect. 1 aura from urself and 1 from a teammate. Doesn't work with 3 or more though.. And both of those items have unique aura so it should work with manamanipulator too.